# Render OS-specific windows to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing

As part of a game idea, I need to procedurally generate images of a desktop cluttered with randomly generated windows. Desirably the frames of the windows will match to the L&F of the program. To fit this need, I am using a `JDesktopPane` with `JInternalFrame`s to render the windows and paint them onto a `BufferedImage`. My code is as such:

```
JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
desktopPane.setSize(1920, 1080);
JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame();
internalFrame.setVisible(true);
internalFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
desktopPane.add(internalFrame);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1920, 1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
desktopPane.paintAll(image.getGraphics());

ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("./desktop.png"));
```

However this code does not create an image of a window in the program L&F, instead it generates a clear and empty image of the appropriate size. Yet if the `JDesktopPane` is added to a `JFrame` and the frame made visible, calling `myJFrame.paintAll(image.getGraphics())` renders perfectly fine. So, how can I paint components that are not visible / displayable or added to a `JFrame`? Or is there a simpler way to render windows in a cross-platform way?

Comment: Try using `printAll` instead of `paintAll`

Comment: @MadProgrammer attempted using `printAll`, it succeeds at drawing parts of the frame to the image, but not all of it. Depending on the L&F more or less of the frame is left out of the image. (eg. borders are missing, content appears black, buttons on the frames don't show up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some playing around, a system look and feel provides the decorations for the frames, this means, that until the component is attached to a native peer, the frame decorations can't be painted...

This means you need to use a `JFrame`, now the good news is, you can use `pack` to do just that...

[image: Desktop]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        desktopPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Testing");
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
        internalFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        desktopPane.add(internalFrame);

        frame.add(desktopPane);
        frame.pack();

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1920, 1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        desktopPane.printAll(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("./desktop.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame.dispose();
    }

}
```

You should also use `printAll` over `paintAll`, mostly because it disables double buffering